# Power for Windows 10 on Raspberry 3B+

Tags: pi-3, windows-iot

can me anybody tell me the Voltage and the Ampere for a power supply I Need for using Windows 10 IoT on a Raspberry 3B+?
Many thanks in advance!
Werner

Comment: 5V 2.5A - same as if you run raspbian

Answer (score 3):

You need 5V +/- 0.25V at 2.5amps.

This will support USB devices. If you're not using USB, you can get by with less.

I recommend either using a USB cable designed for charging rather than one designed for general purpose.

I also recommend a quality power supply that produces 5.2V to allow for some resistance in the cable. A lot of the questions here describing problems are caused by poor power supplies.